# How does register % rbx hold the previous value in a Recursive call

Tags: recursion, assembly

The C and assembly code:

```
long pcount_r(unsigned long x) {
    if (x == 0) return 0;
    else return (x & 1) + pcount_r (x>>1);
}

pcoutn_r:
    movl  $0,   %eax
    testq %rdi, %rdi
    je .L6
    pushq %rbx
    movq  %rdi, %rbx
    andl  $1,   %ebx
    shrq  %rdi
    call  pcount_r
    addq  %rbx, %rax
    popq  %rbx 
.L6:
    rep; ret
```

If passing function a value x = 5 (binary representation is 0101). Register %rdi is the x value, and %rbx holds x value by "movq  %rdi, %rbx" before pass "x>>1" to the next recursive call. Therefore, %rbx holds 0101, then 010, then 01.

```
The first call of pcount_r:
%rdi        %rbx
0101  -->   0101 

The second call of pcount_r:
%rdi        %rbx
010   -->   010 

The third call and etc...
```

%rbx can only hold one value at the time, To me, it seems just overwriting the previous value of %rbx, rather than saving data on a stack. My question is: how can %rbx restore the previous %rbx value when a recursive call ends?

more details about this function can be found in this link. 
[Recursive Procedures at time 55:00](https://scs.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Viewer.aspx?id=2994255f-923b-4ad4-8fb4-5def7fd802cd)

Answer (score 0):

I see. My mistake is that I thought register %rbx is holding the x value. But In fact, %rbx is just holding x value temporarily, assembly code "pushq %rbx" pushes %rbx value to the stack before passing the next %rdi to %rbx. Similarly, the value is restored by "popq  %rbx".

Comment: I think that explanation is still missing a subtle detail (about calling convention). The function adheres to the calling convention, where `rbx` has to be preserved, so it does preserve the current value ahead of modifying it. And it stores 0 or 1 (from the `and`) in `ebx` and calls (itself) another function adhering to the calling convention, so after that other call returns, the `ebx` still holds that 0 or 1 ... it is used (added to `eax`) and then original `ebx` is restored. Also thanks to the one `push`, it keeps stack 16B aligned ahead of call, which is often required on x64.